# Creating a new account on SuperUser

Tags: support, login, superuser

Folks over at superuser told me to ask this here.

(1) Start here: https://superuser.com/

Hit "sign up"

(2) "Do you already have an account on one of these sites?"

Click the logo for "StackExchange"

(3) Fill in email addr & pwd, hit "sign in"

(4) I get:

SuperUser
Log In

Not Found
This page could not be found.

I refresh the page and end up back on (3)

Mind you, during all this I am already logged in to StackExchange: https://stackexchange.com/users/1774372/diagon

I am using google chrome on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Sure you registered Stack Exchange OpenID? Maybe you use Google?

Comment: No.  StackExchange, OpenID. I don't use google.  or facebook.

Comment: Well, being logged in on one site is not relevant, site can't technically access credentials stored on your computer of other sites even though they're all under the same parent domain. To debug this can you please try again with Chrome's Network tab open? (F12 --> Network) then see if you spot anything suspicious e.g. 404 or 403 errors in the tab.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Ok, each of these pages are giving me some errors.  I see repeatedly under the "Name/Path", "invalid".  "Initiator" is usually "Other", but in the transition from (2) to (3) I get an initiator which is "login:25 Parser".  Then, once I try to log in, I get a few of the previous errors, plus a new one labeled "Submit openid.stackexchange.com/affiliate/form/login".  Under that, the headers are: Request URL:https://openid.stackexchange.com/affiliate/form/login/submit
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found  (plus a lot of other stuff).

Comment: The 404 is normal and happens on all sites except this Meta, think it's due to the change in the login/signup paths that isn't yet network wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it was the long-ago-installed-but-then-completely-ignored CSFire addon to Chrome.

You can set the "local policy" to avoid this:

Any POST request
from https://openid.stackexchange.com/affiliate/form
to https://superuser.com/users/authenticate
will be ACCEPTED

I'll add that once the account has been set up, the local policy is not needed to log on.  So it's up to you if you really want to do it, or just turn the addon off while you're signing up.

Comment: Oh, should have guessed it might be a rough addon. Thanks for sharing!